# NSFileManager: Copy a file atomically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, file-io, nsfilemanager

in my iPhone projects, I am currently copying files using `NSFileManager`'s `-copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:` method. However, the docs so not say anything about atomicity, so I might run into trouble if my app tries to read a file that is currently being replaced by another thread. 
Is there a way to copy or replace a file atomically? I am searching for something like `NSData`'s `-writeDataToFilr:atomically:`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How do you use `NSFileManager`? According to the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html), it says the following:

> In iOS and Mac OS X v 10.5 and later you should consider using `[[NSFileManager alloc] init]` rather than the singleton method `defaultManager`. Instances of `NSFileManager` are considered thread-safe when created using `[[NSFileManager alloc] init]`.

Comment: Indeed, I used the singleton instance. And I overlooked the information in the very first paragraph. Shame on me.

Comment: Thread safety and atomic file copying are quite different things though.